# Why do i need to use batch files to run java programs?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, path, environment-variables

I have bothe that java 1.7 JDK installed and the Java 1.7 JRE installed and for some reason, i can use the JDK in eclipse but if i am going to run any java program then i am forced to use a batch file. My path is: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\javaw.exe\" but for some reason the jre inside is not registering

Comment: That would be one of the reasons.  You might also want to setup special class paths and other requirements which can't be done after Java is started.  It is likely that you JRE is setup within you path environment variable, so the OS will run it.  You could check/modify the path variable to include the JDK instead, if that's what you're trying to do

Comment: @MadProgrammer How exactly would i do that?

Comment: You'd start by googling.  Go to the control panel, select system, select advanced system settings, click environment variables, find the path entry in the system variables, click edit.  Copy the contents to a text editor and make the changes, copy the contents back again and select okay all the way back to the system window.  Close any console windows you have open, reopen then and try typing `java -version`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I got java -version to output the correct thing Thanks!